# How do name servers ensure that the server claiming to host a domain is actually operated by that domain?

Tags: dns, linode

I recently started using linode to host my site.
Prior to using linode, I normally used hosting offered by my domain registrar. In those cases, i thought I understood how DNS worked, because the registrar automatically updated your DNS records to point to the server hosing the site.

When following linodes guide, to setting up a website: https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/hosting-a-website

Their instructions tell you to set the DNS servers as:

ns1.linode.com
ns2.linode.com
ns3.linode.com
...

But the point I am making is, that ANYONE can open an account on linode, and fill in the same DNS settings! So now anyone trying to access your website, could be directed to someone else who wants to pretend to be your site!

Am I correct in understanding how DNS works ? I know that the only way to ensure (from a visitors perspective) that a site being visited is actually the domain intended is to install a certificate (https) etc. But based on the above instructions, it seems almost trivial to pretend to be someone else, if they also use linode.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on DNS so my answer may be mistaken, but I had the same question so looked into this.

I think your understanding is correct, and this seems to be a problem but apparently it happens rarely in practice so hosting providers (including Linode) aren't doing anything about it.

[Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-does-do-verify-domain-ownership) is Ryan Quinn from DigitalOcean (another hosting company that has this problem) answering a similar question:

> A domain can only exist on one account so any user attempting to add it would not be able to. Cases where a domain already exists or is hijacked are extremely rare (I've seen 3 cases in 2+ years and in each case it was a former owner of the domain who still had records in place). In these rare cases the user can open a support ticket where we will verify the domain whois information against their billing details to verify ownership.

[Here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49612/how-does-digitalocean-dns-verify-the-owner-of-a-domain) is a question on Information Security Stack Exchange that asks the same thing.

In the case of DigitalOcean, I found a [post](https://thehackerblog.com/floating-domains-taking-over-20k-digitalocean-domains-via-a-lax-domain-import-system/index.html) ([HackerNews discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12364297)) of someone describing how they took over around 20,000 inactive domain names that pointed to DigitalOcean's nameservers. I haven't found anything similar for Linode, although I imagine basically the same attack is possible (2020 Update: This actually recently happened to someone I know, where their website got taken over by a spammer after they took down their Linode without changing the DNS settings to stop pointing to Linode).

[Amazon Route 53](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Route_53) seems to use randomly generated nameservers (rather than Linode/DigitalOcean's constant `ns1.linode.com` etc.) to make this attack highly unlikely to succeed.

[Apparently](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-does-do-verify-domain-ownership) some other services (Google Apps?) "verify domain ownership by requiring the domain owner to add a TXT record to their domain with a special code."

Answer (score 0):

So what? Someone may use the same DNS servers. But they can't register for the same domain. Once you have registered for `example.org`, you own that domain and nobody else will be able to register for it.

---

You have registered for `example.org` and use the following DNS configuration at Linode:

```
Domain             | Nameserver
-------------------+---------------------
example.org        | ns1.linode.com
example.org        | ns2.linode.com
...                | ...
```

An "evil hacker" may have registered `evil-hacker.com` and uses this configuration:

```
Domain             | Nameserver
-------------------+----------------------
evil-hacker.com    | ns1.linode.com
evil-hacker.com    | ns2.linode.com
...                | ...
example.org        | ns1.linode.com  << Those are the lines that bug you, right?
example.org        | ns2.linode.com
```

For simplicity's sake let's say that the IP of your site is `1.1.1.1` and the IP of the evil hacker's site is `2.2.2.2`. You are worried that because the "hacker" used the same DNS configuration, your site `example.org` might resolve to `2.2.2.2`, right?

This is what happens, when I try to resolve `example.org`:

1. I connect to the DNS root servers to find out which nameserver is responsible for the `org` top-level domain.
2. I connect to the nameserver of the `org` top-level domain and ask it for the IP address of `example.org`. The `org` nameserver is managed by your domain registrar. It will look up the information *you* entered and tells me look at one of the linode nameservers.
3. I connect to `ns1.linode.com` and ask it for the IP address of `example.org`. Linode knows which IP your site has and answers me with `1.1.1.1`.

In the above process, I will never see `evil-hacker.com` or `2.2.2.2`. Since our evil hacker (hopefully) can't control the DNS root servers, the nameserver of the `org` top-level domain or the Linode nameservers, all DNS requests for your site will be answered by "trusted" name servers.

However, a hacker might intercept DNS traffic from *my* particular machine. He might install malware that always resolves `example.org` to his IP address `2.2.2.2` (e.g. [`/etc/hosts`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29)) or compromise my network router. So using an SSL certificate for your site is still a good idea :).

Comment: Why do you think ns1.linode.com will answer with 1.1.1.1 instead of 2.2.2.2 ? Linode doesn't do anything to even check whether you are the same person who registered the domain, and has no way of knowing if you are the hacker or owner. Your example illustrates my problem! :)

Comment: @John Because Linode *knows* that `example.org` is under `1.1.1.1`. At least it should.... Looking back at [the hosting tutorial](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/hosting-a-website#adding-dns-records), it seems like you have to also register your domain with Linode (first image in the Adding DNS Records section). I *guess* (and hope) that they won't accept a second registration for `example.org` and can thus map `example.org` to your account which they *know* has the address `1.1.1.1`.

Comment: That is incorrect - you don't register domains with linode. I don't think you read the tutorial carefully, that image has nothing to do with registering a domain. :) The whole point of my question is, that they do not verify if a person claiming to be hosting a server meant for a domain, actually is the registered owner of that domain! I guess this is just how DNS is, and the only way to prevent spoofing is to use certificates. Its quite pathetic. XD Try creating two linode accounts, and spoofing one of the domains.